# Inequality homogeneous wave equation

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am starting to study PDEs and the professor gave us the following exercise.

For $(\varphi^0,\varphi^1)\in L^2(\Omega)\times H^{-1}(\Omega)$, consider the following equation

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\varphi^{\prime \prime}-\Delta \varphi=0 & \text { in }(0, T) \times \Omega \\ \varphi=0 & \text { on }(0, T) \times \partial \Omega \\ \varphi(0, \cdot)=\varphi^{0}, \varphi^{\prime}(0, \cdot)=\varphi^{1} & \text { in } \Omega\end{array}\right.
$$
If $\left(\varphi, \varphi^{\prime}\right) \in C\left([0, T], L^{2}(\Omega) \times H^{-1}(\Omega)\right)$ is the unique weak solution, prove that
$$
\|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}\left(0, T ; L^{2}(\Omega)\right)}^{2}+\left\|\varphi^{\prime}\right\|_{L^{\infty}\left(0, T ; H^{-1}(\Omega)\right)}^{2} \leq\left\|\left(\varphi^{0}, \varphi^{1}\right)\right\|_{L^{2}(\Omega) \times H^{-1}(\Omega)}^{2}.
$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: Can you prove this if $L^2$ is replaced with $H^1$ and $H^{-1}$ is replaced with $L^2$?

Comment: @HansEngler indeed I do not understand why he is using these functional spaces. Do you know about it? coukd you explain it to me, please?

Comment: Formally, consider the inner product of the left hand side with $\Delta^{-1} \varphi' $ and integrate by parts. An identity will follow that proves the statement.  Of course you have to justify that that is allowed.

Comment: @HansEngler  thanks professor! Let me ask you, please: why sometimes the functional space is $H^{1}$ and others it is $H^{-1}$? Which cases are necessary the Sobolev space with negative exponent?

Comment: It's generally useful to have more than one setting in which to study a problem. The $H^1 \times L^2$ setting has a natural physical explanation (energy space), but other settings may have advantages e.g. for numerical schemes. I don't know the exact advantages of using a $L^2 \times H^{-1}$ setting for thr wave equation.